# Kendo Ui Angular with Bootstrap / Material Theme

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

As described in documentation I have configured bootstrap modules using NPM. And applied the CSS in component as well.

Shouldn't this automatically apply the bootstrap theme on our grids? Do I need to manually apply CSS classes on each kendo widgets?

[Kendo Material Theme](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-material/)

[Kendo Bootstrap](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use material theme or bootstrap theme. Both of them will not be applied at the same time. Or you can create a custom css as per your requirement, go to the below link to do so,

http://themebuilder.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui.

To achieve the required UI, you will have to create a custom css, and you will have to go to the Kendo site and use theme builder to create the custom css. The above link is directed to theme builder on kendo site.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18095805)

Comment: To achieve the required UI, you will have to create a custom css, as mentioned in the comment. You will have to go to the Kendo site and use theme builder to create the custom css. The above link is directed to theme builder on kendo site.

Comment: Take it easy, the comment is automatically generated by system wile reviewing. Be careful about posting a link answer, you need to explain why you have to post this link. And now you have done it well, I will help to improve your answer.